# Client wants me to upload to apple store without admin and without key

Tags: ios, app-store

I made an application for a client. He added me as a team member, but without admin/agent rights. In order to upload the application to apple store, I need a distribution provisioning profile, the distribution certificate associated with it, and the key that was used to create the certificate, exported from the mac where it was created. As I know, there is no way to use the distribution provisioning profile without both distribution certificate and the key. The client doesn't want to give me the key but he also doesn't want to give me admin. 
There is a 3rd solution, to create my own distribution certificate on his account using a private key from my mac, but I noticed that the maximum number of distribution certificates is 3, and the client already has 3. 
I doubt there is any problem security wise for providing my distribution certificate in there. Is there? 
I also am not sure if the client should accept my own distribution certificate to be used for uploading the application. Should he?
Also, assuming that all 3 distribution certificates slots are taken and there is no way to obtain a free slot, what should I ask the client to do, in order to assure him that all is safe and good.
Also, is there any other way to upload his application without him giving me admin or key?

Comment: offtopic as it is net really about programming

Comment: I wouldn't mind changing the tag though I am unable to which should be the most appropriate one, so that I drag attention of everyone that is interested in app store, and apple developer account related issues.

Comment: the tag isn't the issue - SO is just not the site for this question IMHO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If they are touchy about this, which they don't need to be, they could provide you with the cert and its key and, once you have uploaded the app, revoke the cert. meaning you wouldn't be able to do anything with it. They can then just generate a new one as and when they need it.

Comment: Does the client needs to wait with revoking the certificate until application is approved?

Comment: It would make more sense, although it's not a requirement. If the application was rejected however and the client had already revoked the cert, then you'd needed to resubmit and need a new cert and key.

Comment: I am just trying to make sure that apple reviewers won't reject for not existing a valid signing at the time of review.